# terraform list of string get method failed

Tags: tensorflow

I have two file called eks-cluster.tf and eks-clsuter-tfvars these file contains to get the list of admin users from the variable file called eks-cluster.tf while execution of terraform plan command getting below error.

eks-cluster.tf

```
variable "admin_users" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "List of Kubernetes admins."
```

eks-cluster-tfvars

```
admin_users = ["aaaa", "bbbbb"]
```

Error log from terraform plan command

```
 Error: Error in function call
│
│   on .terraform\modules\eks-cluster\outputs.tf line 3, in output "cluster_id":
│    3:   value       = element(concat(aws_eks_cluster.this.*.id, list("")), 0)
│
│ Call to function "list" failed: the "list" function was deprecated in
│ Terraform v0.12 and is no longer available; use tolist([ ... ]) syntax to
│ write a literal list.
```

Comment: which version of terraform are you using ?

Comment: version Terraform v0.15.3

Comment: Try with 14 or 12

Comment: Not working as well after down grading version 0.12.14

Comment: Above issue has been resolved with version 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's due to the version issue you can down grade the version to **14** or **12**.

it will work.